# Invisible Fusion Chart in the modal dialog window not exporting

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, fusioncharts

I have a modal dialog where I show 3 fusion charts in it, but only 2 are displayed when the modal opens. To see the 3rd one we have to scroll down. Now I have a print icon and on its click I export all three graphs to create a PDF.

The code is like this (using CoffeeScript):

```
@primaryChartObject = getChartFromId("fusionChartsInstanceCompareCurrent");
if @primaryChartObject && @primaryChartObject.hasRendered()
    @primaryChartObject.exportChart({});

@upstreamChartObject = getChartFromId("fusionChartsInstanceCompareUpstream");
if @upstreamChartObject && @upstreamChartObject.hasRendered()
    @upstreamChartObject.exportChart({});

@differenceChartObject = getChartFromId("fusionChartsInstanceCompareDifference");
if @differenceChartObject && @differenceChartObject.hasRendered()
    @differenceChartObject.exportChart({});
```

The charts start exporting, but on the modal dialog, the progress bar is shown only for the visible charts. When I scroll down, the 3rd one's progress bar is shown, but 1st one's is paused. I have to move up and down a couple of times to make sure all the graphs are exported. And then the exported **pdf** appear properly.

The problem is if user doesn't know about this scrolling, then he/she is never going to get the PDF of the chart. How can this be solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exporting of the charts, which are not in the viewable portion of the browser naturally does not take place as the Flash charts are not rendered.

Comment: Yes that is what finally did. Scrolled the page down to render the invisible chart.